# I Can't Run Any Tests With Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

Every time I try to run a test with rspec i get this screen [rspec error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnK64.png) I don't understand what could be the problem I installed the bundle

Comment: Show your `spec_helper.rb`.

Comment: Instead of `I Can't Run Any Tests With Rspec` that does not indicate a concrete problem use smth like `undefined method:...`. Check [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/aapPP is this what you mean

Comment: 1. Please copy+paste the **text** from the error message on StackOverflow. Do not link to an image of the error. 2. Show us your code! Ideally, a [mcve]. This is probably an issue with your library versioning, but we don't know what you're using.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/lsegal/yard/issues/1062

The shared_context_metadata_behaviour was added in 3.5, if it is telling you it is undefined you either need to update RSpec or remove the method.
Run

```
bundle exec rspec -v
```

If it is 3.4 or lower, then change the RSpec line in your gemfile to:

```
gem 'rspec', '~> 3.5'
```

Bundle install, then rspec away.